# jQuery listening to drop down menu forces specific select element value

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have some jQuery which is designed to fire when any `<select>` element on a page is changed. If the value of that element is "Other" it removes a class from a div of the same name as the select element.

Here is my code:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var x = $(this).attr('name');
    if($(this).val('Other')) {
         $('div[name="' + x + '"]').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
         $('div[name="' + x + '"]').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

It works in that on page load the div is hidden, and if "Other" is selected the div appears.

However:

Any selection from the dropdown results in "Other" being selected (and the code firing)

It is therefore impossible to select anythign other than "Other", even if attempting to change it after wards.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if($(this).val('Other'))
// this will set value to Other so if condition will always be true no matter what ever you select.
```

to

```
if($(this).val() == 'Other') 
// this will check if value is equal to Other
```

or better

```
if(this.value == 'Other')
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks: could you explain why it didn't work my way? The "if" seems like it should stop it being prescriptive?

Comment: @Gideon `if($(this).val('Other'))`  code of your will not check if value is `Other`  but will set the value to `Other` which will return `true` so the if condition is always `true`.Even if you change value this condition will always be true.